# Passing data between R and Python - How to convert arrow table to tibble/dataframe?

Tags: r, pandas, dplyr, pyarrow, reticulate

The goal is:

1. Take Tidy data from R, convert it to Arrow data
2. Pass arrow data to python, convert to Pandas df
3. Manipulate Pandas df, convert it back to arrow
4. Retrieve arrow data from python, convert back to Tidy data

I can't seem to get past that last step.

```
# R
library(reticulate)
library(dplyr)
library(arrow)

# Python
import pyarrow 
import pandas
```

#### Make a tibble, convert it to Arrow table, pass it to Python

```
arrow_dat <- arrow::as_arrow_table(tibble(col = c(1,2,3)))
py_taxa_arrow <- r_to_py(arrow_dat)
```

#### Convert data to Pandas Dataframe, edit it, convert to Arrow

```
r.py_taxa_arrow

pyarrow.Table
col: double
----
col: [[1,2,3]]

py_taxa_arrow_to_pd = r.py_taxa_arrow.to_pandas()

py_taxa_arrow_edited = pandas.DataFrame(py_taxa_arrow_to_pd) + 1
py_taxa_arrow_edited

   col
0  2.0
1  3.0
2  4.0

py_taxa_arrow_edited_converted = pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(py_taxa_arrow_edited)
py_taxa_arrow_edited_converted

pyarrow.Table
col: double
----
col: [[2,3,4]]
```

#### Retrieve the edited data

```
py_taxa_arrow_edited <- r_to_py(py$py_taxa_arrow_edited_converted)
py_taxa_arrow_edited

pyarrow.Table
col: double
----
col: [[2,3,4]]
```

#### Convert to Tibble

```
tibble(py_taxa_arrow_edited)

Error in `tibble()`:
! All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
✖ Column `py_taxa_arrow_edited` is a
  `pyarrow.lib.Table/pyarrow.lib._Tabular/pyarrow.lib._PandasConvertible/pyarrow.lib._Weakrefable/python.builtin.object`
  object.
Backtrace:
 1. tibble::tibble(py_taxa_arrow_edited)

 Error in tibble(py_taxa_arrow_edited) : 
✖ Column `py_taxa_arrow_edited` is a
  `pyarrow.lib.Table/pyarrow.lib._Tabular/pyarrow.lib._PandasConvertible/pyarrow.lib._Weakrefable/python.builtin.object`
  object.
 
9.
    
stop(fallback)
 
8.
    
signal_abort(cnd, .file)
 
7.
    
abort(x, class, ..., call = call, parent = parent, use_cli_format = TRUE)
 
6.
    
tibble_abort(call = call, problems("All columns in a tibble must be vectors:", 
    x = paste0("Column ", name_or_pos(names, positions), " is ", 
        classes)), names = names)
 
5.
    
abort_column_scalar_type(names_x[is_xd], pos[is_xd], classes, 
    call)
 
4.
    
check_valid_cols(set_names(list(x), name), call = call)
 
3.
    
check_valid_col(res, col_names[[j]], j, call)
 
2.
    
tibble_quos(xs, .rows, .name_repair)
 
1.
    
tibble(py_taxa_arrow_edited)
```

Edit: Final Solution

```
# R
arrow_dat <- arrow::as_arrow_table(tibble(col = c(1,2,3)))
py_taxa_arrow <- r_to_py(arrow_dat)
# Python
py_taxa_arrow_to_pd = r.py_taxa_arrow.to_pandas()
py_taxa_arrow_edited = py_taxa_arrow_to_pd + 1
py_taxa_arrow_edited_converted = pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(py_taxa_arrow_edited)
# R
as_tibble(py$py_taxa_arrow_edited_converted)

col
<dbl>   
2               
3               
4
```

Comment: The best way is often to store the data in a non-program dependent. eg tsv,csv,txt etc.. Might be easier to read the data cross language.

Comment: what Onyambu said, but also, this just seems needlessly complicated. Is there a reason you want to do the data analysis on the pandas dataframe? Is it because you are more familiar with/comfortable with pandas?

Comment: Should this not be py_to_r?
`py_taxa_arrow_edited <- r_to_py(py$py_taxa_arrow_edited_converted)`

Also for Onyambu and mark, zero-copy movement of data is what arrow is for: saving massive amounts of data, reading them back in, saving again and finally another read vs. passing a pointer around.

Here are the specific Arrow R package docs describing this scenario: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/python.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your reprex:

- you used `r_to_py` (a noop as it is already in python) instead of `py_to_r`
- using `as_tibble` instead of `tibble` correctly converts it to a tibble

I have recreated the fixed reprex so it can be run in one go:

```r
library(reticulate)
library(dplyr)
library(arrow)

pa <- import('pyarrow')
pd <- import('pandas')

arrow_dat <- arrow::as_arrow_table(tibble(col = c(1,2,3)))

# Convert to python
py_taxa_arrow <- r_to_py(arrow_dat)
py_taxa_arrow

# Do stuff
py_taxa_arrow_to_pd = py_taxa_arrow$to_pandas()
py_taxa_arrow_to_pd

py_taxa_arrow_edited <- py_taxa_arrow_to_pd + 1
py_taxa_arrow_edited

# Convert back
# py_to_r converts to data.frame
# pa$Table$from_pandas converts to Arrow table, so you want to use
# that if you have larger (than memory) data.
py_taxa_arrow_edited_converted <- pa$Table$from_pandas(py_taxa_arrow_edited) 
py_taxa_arrow_edited_converted

as_tibble(py_taxa_arrow_edited_converted)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. After py_taxa_arrow_edited, don't we need to convert back to an arrow table for that in-memory transfer with pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(py_taxa_arrow_edited) ?

Comment: huh. I guess I deleted that accidentally, I was using pa$Table$from_pandas() before. But this code runs so I guess the conversion is implicit? Might be due to pandas using pyarrow under the hood by default now?

Comment: Interesting both py_to_r and pa$Table$from_pandas work to prepare data for as_tibble(). py_to_r converts to data.frame and pa$Table$from_pandas converts to an arrow table so that is likely what you want to use if you have larger data on hand.(add to answer)

Comment: Small typo in your answer but otherwise this is it! Thanks for the help. It's py_taxa_arrow_edited_converted = pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(py_taxa_arrow_edited) in Python not py_taxa_arrow_edited_converted <- pa$Table$from_pandas(py_taxa_arrow_edited) in R. I posted the final solution in my original post.